# Linux last login get the logins yesterday and email it the next day or specific time via crontab

Tags: cron, login, last

I need to know the last login yesterday and email it to me via crontab....

Since the last command shows all the login you need to scroll up. Using grep and cut might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script for yesterday..
yesterday.sh

```
#Get the date month and date cut the necessary date
```

ystd=$(date --date yesterday | cut -d' ' -f2,3) tdy=$(date --date today | cut -d' '
    -f2,3)

```
#show the date yesterday Month and date
```

echo ${ystd}
    #show the date today Month and date 
echo ${tdy}

```
#grep the date try checking the tdy since you may have no login yesterday
```

last | grep "$tdy"

email it

- 8 * * * /user/yesterday.sh | mail -s "Last Login Yesterday" me@example.net